# x11 file manager with photo preview

Tags: file-management, image-viewer

I organise photos in filesystem directories. I want the ability to preview one photo in a big frame and to preview many photos in grids. I want basic filesystem copy rename move delete operations for directories and photos and other file types.

Comment: Am I assuming right that "x11" means you want this for Linux? And that this functionality must be integrated in a (regular) file manager (not an image viewer that also can browse directories)? If so, what DE (KDE, LXDE, XFCE …) must it work on? What other features must the file manager have? Are commercial solutions acceptable, or must it be open-source and free?

Answer (score 1):

### [gThumb](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/gthumb)

as far as i know gThumb accomplishes all your requirements and even more like easy editing, printing, deduplication and some further features via extensions.

### [pix](https://github.com/linuxmint/pix)

pix is the "platform-independent" fork of gThumb 3.2.8, which will suit your environment better if don't use GNOME3.

### [Geeqie](http://geeqie.org/)

maybe also Geeqie as a even more lightweight alternative is worth a look.

Answer (score -1):

## digiKam

What about digiKam? I am using that now for a couple of years and it works quite well. Have a look at digiKam.org

Comment: How do I browse photographs in random filesystem locations outside the library directories?